# Multiple sticky (fixed) table columns with dynamic widths using CSS only?

Tags: css

I need the first three columns of my html table to remain fixed on the screen while the user scrolls horizontally on the remaining columns.

For a single column, I could just use

```
.sticky-col1{
   position: sticky;
   left: 0;
}
```

Of course, I couldn't use this class for the second column because the two `left: 0;` positions would cause the columns to stack on top of each other.

A common solution I've seen requires fixed width columns and manually adjusting the left position of each column. But what about a scenario where the column widths aren't fixed and depend on content?

Well, then just use javascript to query the DOM to get each columns width, and update the CSS accordingly, right?

Unfortunately, in my case, accessing the document appears not to be possible due to security restrictions within the framework I'm using (specifically, Lightning Locker Service for Salesforce.com lightning/aura framework).

So I'm looking for a solution that allows for dynamic column widths but doesn't require accessing the document object. Is it possible?